# What does the conflict "Both Modified" mean in git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am just pulling some code from a repository on github. Then In vsCode I see the editor is suggesting to solve the merge conflict. Then I accept the incoming changes and solve the merge conflict. But the file is showing error and when I hover over that it tells me that conflict: both modified. What does that mean.

In codium/vscode, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Anything shown as a pop-up when you hover over it is specific to VSCode. The "both modified" is the standard kind of Git conflict, but why VSCode is showing that to you when you hover over the file name, I have no idea.

Answer (score -1):

I am still a beginner at git, warning. This is real code that worked, but it is no guarantee that it will work the same for other things. I hope it still helps someone.

I had the same conflict, and here is what I did in the shell (command: `history`). It pops up when you have different work done in parallel and you have a merge conflict that must be solved before it pops up.

Being in MY_BRANCH, I ran:

```sh
 2004  git stash
 2005  git checkout master
 2006  git fetch
 2007  git pull
 2018  git checkout MY_BRANCH
 2019  git log
# You may also use `git reflog` instead of `git log` to see the 
# numbers of the references.
 2024  git branch
 2026  git status
 2027  git rebase -i 633e0424523c4933ba6ab...
 2029  git rebase -i HEAD~
 2030  git log
 2031  git stash apply
 2032  git status
 2033  git add .
 2034  git rebase --continue
 2035  git log
 2036  git push -f
 2037  git branch
 2038  git status
 2039  git diff master
```

Main steps:

- `git stash` (in MY_BRANCH)
- `git pull` your master
- rebase to the commit after which different work has been done in parallel
- then `apply` your `stash` to the rebased commit (see all stashes with `git stash list`
- `add .` your changes to the stage
- `rebase --continue` to take over the work back to MY_BRANCH
- `push -f` the updated work to your branch
- check `diff`, the error of "Both Modified" should be gone (in my case at least).

UPDATE:

Even after these changes, I got the same thing again: "Both modified". I am not sure how this came up again since a lot of changes have been made since the answer above. Yet, with some bad luck, the above code does not fully show the way out.

What I had to do when "Both modified" popped up again:

```sh
 1998  git status
```

gives:

> On branch MY_BRANCH Your branch and 'origin/MY_BRANCH' have diverged,
> and have 4 and 1 different commits each, respectively.   (use "git
> pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

```sh
 1999  git reset --hard origin/MY_BRANCH
 2000  git pull
 2001  git status
 2002  git add .
 2003  git commit --amend
 2004  git push -f
```

UPDATE2:

I had the issue again, it showed up during rebase since my main and the origin/main were not the same: `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.`
Two steps:

```sh
git checkout main
git reset HEAD^ --soft
```

were all that was needed. I used the `--soft` parameter to save it in case of problems. After the reset, the main and the 'origin/main' were the same again and the error that had popped up before during rebase was gone.